# Azure Pipeline Integration Tests hang indefinitely (LocalDb issue?)

Tags: c#, azure-pipelines, .net-6.0, xunit, localdb

I have a pipeline for integration testing which hangs whithout much info. It worked 2 weeks ago, and when I ran the pipeline again last week it didn't.

Locally all tests work like a charm.

Things I've tried:

- rolling back my code and pipeline.yml to the same commit as when last working
- setting up LocalDB before starting tests
- installing SQL Express version from MSI in separate yml task
- running tests from ps script where I use `Enter-VsDevShell`
- sqllocaldb info/stop/delete/start all gives the same versions as my local machine
- changing connection string from mssqllocaldb -> gives another error
- running on windows-2019 instead of windows-latest
- building and testing in debug build config
- Test task with publishRunAttachments: false
- added blame hang or it would run forever
- added -p:ParallelizeTestCollections=false" to `dotnet test`-command
- added `console;verbosity=detailed` but i cannot see anything extra of value
- Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb in connection string
- `sqlcmd -l 60 -S "(localdb)\mssqllocaldb" -Q "SELECT @@VERSION;"` is working

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "StorageDbConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=StorageTestDb;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true",
  }
}
```

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="FluentAssertions" Version="6.10.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="17.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Moq" Version="4.18.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Respawn" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.4.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.4.5">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="3.2.0">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Original task from pipeline.yml:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  name: dotnetTest
  displayName: Running tests
  inputs:
    command: 'test'
    projects: '**/*Tests/*.csproj'
    arguments: '--no-build --configuration $(buildConfiguration) --logger "console;verbosity=detailed" --blame-hang --blame-hang-timeout 1min'
    publishTestResults: false
```

Stack trace on blame timeout:

```
The active test run was aborted. Reason: Test host process crashed
Data collector 'Blame' message: The specified inactivity time of 2 minutes has elapsed. Collecting hang dumps from testhost and its child processes.
Data collector 'Blame' message: Dumping 644 - testhost.

Attachments:
  D:\a\1\s\src\Storage\tests\Storage.Application.IntegrationTests\TestResults\7360506b-d062-4e10-8d30-8302c4b56dbd\testhost_644_20230707T081918_hangdump.dmp
  D:\a\1\s\src\Storage\tests\Storage.Application.IntegrationTests\TestResults\7360506b-d062-4e10-8d30-8302c4b56dbd\Sequence_fd411c6d094d49478d7ee506dc44ebfd.xml
Test Run Aborted with error System.Exception: One or more errors occurred.

 ---> System.Exception: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host..
 ---> System.Exception: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Span`1 buffer)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Span`1 buffer)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.ReadByte()
   at System.IO.BinaryReader.Read7BitEncodedInt()
   at System.IO.BinaryReader.ReadString()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CommunicationUtilities.LengthPrefixCommunicationChannel.NotifyDataAvailable()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CommunicationUtilities.TcpClientExtensions.MessageLoopAsync(TcpClient client, ICommunicationChannel channel, Action`1 errorHandler, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---.
The active Test Run was aborted because the host process exited unexpectedly. Please inspect the call stack above, if available, to get more information about where the exception originated from.
```

Are there firewalls or permissions I can set on the pipeline?

Are there any better ways of debugging or finding what's actually timing out?

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it working. Found someone with similar problems as well, but not the same solution: https://github.com/actions/runner-images/issues/7683
I might have been affected by the same changes to the windows image, our troubles seem to have started around the same time.

Once I changed the pipeline task to VSTest I got some more output (Console.WriteLine debug lines added in tests and test setup) I could see the test setup failing before even getting to the test cases.

In my database seed I had a call like `await SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);` that never got finished. I changed it to  `SaveChanges();` and the pipeline started working.

Not sure why it works though, possibly some race condition, deadlock or the like. Running locally worked fine all the time.